# Service Broker is working only first time

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

Service Broker is working only for the first time.

I am new to service broker and learning the same. Doing it for the first time.
I suspected that it is working only for the first time so i changed the name of the service/contract and queue and again tried to test it out it worked that also once it worked. Again I changed the name and tried again it worked once only.

Service  Broker Contract/Service/Queue creation

```
IF NOT EXISTS(  SELECT '*' 
                FROM    sys.service_contracts  
                WHERE NAME = N'TESTContract1234')
BEGIN
        CREATE CONTRACT TESTContract1234
            ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/DialogTimer] SENT BY INITIATOR)
END

    IF NOT EXISTS(  SELECT  '*' 
                FROM    sys.service_queues 
                WHERE   NAME = N'TEST_SCHEDULEDJOBQUEUE1234')
BEGIN
        create  QUEUE TEST_SCHEDULEDJOBQUEUE1234
        WITH STATUS = on, 
        ACTIVATION (    
            PROCEDURE_NAME = testing1_sp,
            MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1, -- we expect max 20 jobs to start simultaneously
            EXECUTE AS 'dbo' );
END

IF NOT EXISTS(  SELECT '*' 
                FROM sys.services 
                WHERE NAME = N'//TESTJOBSERVICE1234')
BEGIN   
        CREATE SERVICE [//TESTJOBSERVICE1234] 
        AUTHORIZATION dbo
        ON QUEUE TEST_SCHEDULEDJOBQUEUE1234 (TESTContract1234)
END
```

SP which gets executed in the Queue

```
create table testing1
(
descr       varchar(255),
seqno       int identity(1,1),
currtime    date
)

create procedure testing1_sp
as
begin
set nocount on

insert into testing1(descr,currtime) values('Service Broker Sample',getdate())

set nocount off

end
```

Script used for Testing

```
    declare @ConversationHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    ,@TimeoutInSeconds udd_int

    SELECT @TimeoutInSeconds = DATEpart(s, dbo.RES_Getdate(0))--, @FirstRunOn);

BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
    FROM SERVICE   [//TESTJOBSERVICE1234]
    TO SERVICE      '//TESTJOBSERVICE1234', 
                    'CURRENT DATABASE'
    ON CONTRACT     TESTContract1234
    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;
```

At the database level, service broker is enabled I checked the same using sys.databases catalog view column name is_broker_enabled.
In sys.conversation_endpoints catalog view one entry is available and state_desc for the same is "STARTED_OUTBOUND"

Please help me debug the issue and understand where I'm making mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `testing1_sp` is not a legal procedure to handle internal activation. A procedure used for internal activation *must* actually process messages on the conversation, which this procedure does not. If a procedure fails to process anything, the queue will eventually be disabled as part of poison message handling.

Comment: To verify @jeroen's claim, take a look at sys.service_queues for your queue. I'd expect that receive and enqueue are disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Checked in the catalog view sys.service_queues and observe receive and enqueue columns are having the value as 1 which means it is enabled.

Comment: Your procedure processes nothing, but it doesn't fail (as in, throw an error) and I'm not sure what the behavior is on that -- if poison message handling doesn't happen, then at least activation should end up disabled. In any case, even just for testing you probably want a procedure here that *does* use a `RECEIVE` to actually get messages from the queue; it won't be representative of what'll actually happen otherwise. (Also, the code you've shown doesn't include a `SEND` to actually do something with the conversation.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt reply. In the receive command i need to read the data from the queue and process it? Where do I have to add this? Can you please guide I'm doing it for the first time please.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials online, for example [this one](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3925256/SQL-Server-Service-Broker-150-Internal-Activation.htm). A full implementation has a bit of boilerplate associated with it, but at its most basic you need at least one `RECEIVE ... FROM Queue` statement to actually make the number of messages in the queue decrease, otherwise SQL Server will conclude your procedure is malfunctioning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tutorials will try it out and get back.